# Run symfony2 on 1and1 server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I copied all files from symfony2.3 in /kunden/homepages/35/d12345/htdocs/ - (I call it home). So it looks like this:

```
home/app/...
home/web/app.php
home/web/app_dev.php
home/web/.htaccess
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Change below before deploying to production
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I got this from this forum. When I am going to type in the browser www.mydomain.com/web/app_dev.php or www.mydomain.com/web/app.php, I am going to get the following message: "You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information."

My writing options are set:

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 u12345 ftpusers    32 Sep 11 19:02 cache
drwxrwxrwx 2 u12345 ftpusers    36 Sep 11 18:57 logs
```

What is wrong? There is a prod.log but no dev.log How can I get it to work? Do I need a .htaccess in my home directory?

Comment: [And have you checked app_dev.php as suggested?](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app_dev.php#L14)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ip-address you're trying to access the application from ( aka your [work/home ip](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) ) to the array allowed ones in your `app_dev.php` to prevent unauthorized people from being able to access your application in the dev environment ...

... or comment out the address-check in `app_dev.php` entirely if you don't care about the security risks.